# How to pass an array from main view to partial view in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've a main view that contains an array received from the corresponding Action and it also contains a partial view reference below

**Create.cshtml** :

```
@model HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.EmployeeMasterA

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ViewData["fs_lbls"] = ViewBag.FS_lbls as string[];
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/EmployeeMasterA/FinalSettlementTAB.cshtml", Model)
}
```

and the referenced partial view above is defined below

**FinalSettlementTAB.cshtml** :

```
@model HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.EmployeeMasterA

    @Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "Department")   

/* Print "ViewData["fs_lbls"]" array defined in the Main View `Create.cshtml` here */
```

I've an array defined in the `Create.cshtml`, now, I want to pass it into the partial view `HR_EmployeeFinalSettlementTAB.cshtml` and print it, What is the proper way to to this?

What I've tried :

I changed the `@Html.Partial()` line into below :

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/EmployeeMasterA/FinalSettlementTAB.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "fs_lbls", ViewData["fs_lbls"] } })
```

and modified the FinalSettlementTAB.cshtml file as below :

```
@model HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.EmployeeMasterA

@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "Department")   

@foreach (var i in ViewData["fs_lbls"] as string[])
{
    @i
}
```

But it throws an exception `InvalidOperationException` at line `@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "Department")` by saying :

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DeptId'.

It throws the above exception whenever I try to pass the array data to the partial view using `ViewDataDictionary`, otherwise, it is working fine, when I'm not.

How do I get rid of the above exception and properly pass array data from main view to the partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you add a new property to `EmployeeMasterA` to store the labels, so that you do not need to use `ViewData` at all.

```
public class EmployeeMasterA
{
    public string[] fs_lbls { get; set; }

    public string SelectedLabel { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Labels
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.fs_lbls == null)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>().ToList();
            }

            return (from label in fs_lbls
                   select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = label,
                Value = label
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeMasterA

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("FinalSettlementTAB", Model)
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

**FinalSettlementTAB.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeMasterA

@Html.DropDownList("SelectedLabel", Model.Labels)
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new EmployeeMasterA();
    viewModel.fs_lbls = new[] {"Label1", "label 2"};

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeMasterA viewModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

You can set the content of `fs_lbls` in the controller action method, before returning the `Create` view. When you post the form, the `SelectedLabel` property will contain the selected item from the dropdown list. Obviously you will need to change the property names to suite your needs, but hopefully this will give you an idea.